# kafka connect JdbcSourceConnector deserialization issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using kafka connect to connect to a database in order to store info on a compacted topic and am having deserialization issues when trying to consume the topic in a spring cloud stream application.

connector config:

```
    {
  "name": "my-connector",
  "config": {
    "name": "my-connector",
    "poll.interval.ms": "86400000",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "oracle-jdbc-string",
    "connection.user": "testid",
    "connection.password": "test",
    "catalog.pattern": "mySchema",
    "table.whitelist": "MY_TABLE",
    "table.types": "TABLE",
    "mode": "bulk",
    "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
    "transforms": "createKey, extractCode, UpdateTopicName",
    "transforms.UpdateTopicName.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.extractCode.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractCode.field": "ID",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "ID",
    "transforms.UpdateTopicName.regex": "(.*)",
    "transforms.UpdateTopicName.replacement": "my_topic",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "topic.prefix": "nt_mny_"
  }
}
```

The connector appears to be working fine and putting the appropriate message on the topic and a sample message looks like this when using the kafka-console-consumer

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost.ntrs.com:9092 --topic nt_mny_ece_alert_avro --from-beginning  --property print.key=true | jq '.'

7247
0
{
  "ID": 7247,
  "USER_SK": 5623,
  "TYP_CDE": "TEST",
  "ALRT_ACTIVE_FLAG": "Y",
  "ALRT_DESC": "My Alert",
  "ALRT_STATUS": "VISIBLE",
  "CREAT_BY": "ME",
  "CREAT_TM": 1593547299565,
  "UPD_BY": "ME",
  "UPD_TM": 1593547299565
}
```

I'm wondering if the 0 printed in between the key and value is the issue or just kafka noise.

The issue I see in the code is

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x17a2241 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7); nested exception is java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x17a2241 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)
```

and my processor/sink code is relatively simple.

```
@StreamListener
public void process(
    @Input(MyAlertsProcessor.MY_ALERT_AVRO) KStream<String, Json> myAlertKconnectStream) {

    myAlertKconnectStream.peek((key,value) -> {
        System.out.println("HELOOOOOO");
        logger.debug("ece/pre: key={}, value={}",key,value);});

}
```

I've spent days trying to figure this out with little to show for it any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using the schema registre? And also why use Avro as name in the topic while you're trying to get JSON

Comment: my intentions are to use avro eventually but for now trying to just make it work with JSON so it's easier to see what data is actually in the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the JSON Schema converter (`io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter`), not the JSON converter (`org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`).

The JSON Schema converter uses the Schema Registry to store the schema, and puts information about it on the front few bytes of the message. That's what's tripping up your code (`Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x17a2241 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)`).

So either use the [JSON Schema deserialiser](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#json-schema-deserializer) in your code (better), or switch to using the `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` converter (less preferable; you throw away the schema then).

More details: https://rmoff.net/2020/07/03/why-json-isnt-the-same-as-json-schema-in-kafka-connect-converters-and-ksqldb-viewing-kafka-messages-bytes-as-hex/

Comment: Learned something new today ! Thanks @RobinMoffatt

Comment: ah ok that makes sense does the same hold true for Avro?  Eventually I would like to use Avro schemas but just started with json since the messages are more legible.

Comment: Yes, the principle (leading bytes) is exactly the same for Avro. In fact, Avro would almost be easier here because whilst JSONSchema *looks* legible, you still need the specific deserialiser to work with it. With Avro it's clear that you do since it appears at "gibberish" if you try to view it without the specific deserialiser.

Comment: I'm trying with Avro now and facing some more deserialization issues: Could not read JSON: Invalid UTF-32 character 0x19d71ee any guess as to why?  just trying to deserialize to a generic record for now.

Comment: Figured it out was using an spring cloud  version Greenwich and when I updated to 2020 the newer version of the StreamListener was able to handle the GenericRecord as expected!  Thanks for the help @RobinMoffat